# Creating new df columns via iteration

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I have a dataframe, `df` which looks like this

```
            Open  High   Low  Close   Volume
Date                                        
2007-03-22  2.65  2.95  2.64   2.86   176389
2007-03-23  2.87  2.87  2.78   2.78    63316
2007-03-26  2.83  2.83  2.51   2.52    54051
2007-03-27  2.61  3.29  2.60   3.28   589443
2007-03-28  3.65  4.10  3.60   3.80  1114659
2007-03-29  3.91  3.91  3.33   3.57   360501
2007-03-30  3.70  3.88  3.66   3.71   185787
```

I'm trying to create a new column, which will takes the df.Open value 5 days ahead from  each df.Open value and subtract it.

So the loop I"m using is this:

```
for i in range(0, len(df.Open)):  #goes through indexes values
    df['5days'][i]=df.Open[i+5]-df.Open[i]    #I use those index values to locate
```

However, this loop is yielding an error.

`KeyError: '5days'`

Not sure why. I got this to temporarily work by removing the  df['5days'][i], but it seems awfully slow. Not sure if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)

```
df['5Days'] = df.Open.diff(5)
print(df)

            Open  High   Low  Close   Volume  5Days
Date                                               
2007-03-22  2.65  2.95  2.64   2.86   176389    NaN
2007-03-23  2.87  2.87  2.78   2.78    63316    NaN
2007-03-26  2.83  2.83  2.51   2.52    54051    NaN
2007-03-27  2.61  3.29  2.60   3.28   589443    NaN
2007-03-28  3.65  4.10  3.60   3.80  1114659    NaN
2007-03-29  3.91  3.91  3.33   3.57   360501   1.26
2007-03-30  3.70  3.88  3.66   3.71   185787   0.83
```

However, per your code, you may want to look ahead and align the results back.  In that case

```
df['5Days'] = -df.Open.diff(-5)
print(df)

            Open  High   Low  Close   Volume  5days
Date                                               
2007-03-22  2.65  2.95  2.64   2.86   176389   1.26
2007-03-23  2.87  2.87  2.78   2.78    63316   0.83
2007-03-26  2.83  2.83  2.51   2.52    54051    NaN
2007-03-27  2.61  3.29  2.60   3.28   589443    NaN
2007-03-28  3.65  4.10  3.60   3.80  1114659    NaN
2007-03-29  3.91  3.91  3.33   3.57   360501    NaN
2007-03-30  3.70  3.88  3.66   3.71   185787    NaN
```

Comment: Works, great. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) with [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html):

```
df['5days'] = df.Open.shift(5).sub(df.Open)
print (df)
            Open  High   Low  Close   Volume  5days
Date                                               
2007-03-22  2.65  2.95  2.64   2.86   176389    NaN
2007-03-23  2.87  2.87  2.78   2.78    63316    NaN
2007-03-26  2.83  2.83  2.51   2.52    54051    NaN
2007-03-27  2.61  3.29  2.60   3.28   589443    NaN
2007-03-28  3.65  4.10  3.60   3.80  1114659    NaN
2007-03-29  3.91  3.91  3.33   3.57   360501  -1.26
2007-03-30  3.70  3.88  3.66   3.71   185787  -0.83
```

Or maybe need substract `Open` with shifted column:

```
df['5days'] = df.Open.sub(df.Open.shift(5))
print (df)
            Open  High   Low  Close   Volume  5days
Date                                               
2007-03-22  2.65  2.95  2.64   2.86   176389    NaN
2007-03-23  2.87  2.87  2.78   2.78    63316    NaN
2007-03-26  2.83  2.83  2.51   2.52    54051    NaN
2007-03-27  2.61  3.29  2.60   3.28   589443    NaN
2007-03-28  3.65  4.10  3.60   3.80  1114659    NaN
2007-03-29  3.91  3.91  3.33   3.57   360501   1.26
2007-03-30  3.70  3.88  3.66   3.71   185787   0.83
```

---

```
df['5days'] = -df.Open.sub(df.Open.shift(-5))
print (df)
            Open  High   Low  Close   Volume  5days
Date                                               
2007-03-22  2.65  2.95  2.64   2.86   176389   1.26
2007-03-23  2.87  2.87  2.78   2.78    63316   0.83
2007-03-26  2.83  2.83  2.51   2.52    54051    NaN
2007-03-27  2.61  3.29  2.60   3.28   589443    NaN
2007-03-28  3.65  4.10  3.60   3.80  1114659    NaN
2007-03-29  3.91  3.91  3.33   3.57   360501    NaN
2007-03-30  3.70  3.88  3.66   3.71   185787    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. Your's as well as PirSquared's both work great. I don't know who to give the best answer accolade to lol.

Comment: It is up to  you ;)

Comment: Sometimes help toss a coin ;)